# how to display blob image stored in mysql database in symfony 2.7.3

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am having trouble displaying blob image on my web site, am using symfony 2.7.3...
i tried to encode the blob data in base 64, am able to display the base 64 value but when i embed it in  nothing happens bellow is my code.
pls what am in doing wrong ??

> controller

```
$badges = $this->getDoctrine() 
     ->getRepository('AppBundle:News')->findAll();
    $images = array();
    foreach ($badges as $key  => $badge) {
         $images[$key] = base64_encode(stream_get_contents($badge->getImage()));

    }

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'badges' => $badges,
         'images' => $images,

    ));
}
```

> view

```
    {% if badges %}
    {% block badge %}
       {% for key,badge in badges %}

             <div style = "margin:4px;height:100px" class="thumbnail">

                 <div class="pull-left">
                           <a href=""><img alt="embeded image"src="data:image/png;base64,{{ images[key] }}" />
                    </div>
                     <div style="width:auto" class = "pull-right" >
                                {{ badge.title }}
                     </div>
                        </a>
             </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is not a proper answer, but I just wanted to suggest you not to store large data in your database, but instead the link to where it is stored on your server as a string. This way you can access your data way easier, and you do not have these kinds of problems. Hope this helps

Comment: 1. Are you sure it's png image?
2. Are you sure images array contains proper image source?

Just make sure that $badge->getImage() returns what stream_get_contents() function expects, and that you have valid base64_encoded image content. (I'd suggest check it out independently of your app - do it manually firstly.)

Comment: @Alex yes i tested it with  both png and jpg images i also have the content of the images array echo and it was in base64. i dont know what to do again *subs*

Comment: This is my get image function ` /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
        
    }`

Comment: @ Guillaume Fache sure it helps... how do i go about the solution you suggested ? do you have sample jobs of such ???!!

Comment: What is exact response of the getImage() method? Are you sure it return a handle which stream_get_contents() expects?

Comment: thanks @alex !! after much research i decided to go with uploading the image and storing the path in the database instead of the image as blob and it worked just fine...

Comment: Yes, that was the point.